# Does Files.readAllBytes() closes the inputstream after reading the file?

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream

Does this java method close the inputstream after reading the file?

Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file"))

Comment: This [javadocs stuff](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) is amazing *Reads all the bytes from a file. The method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been read*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it closes. See it in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)).

> Reads all the bytes from a file. The method ensures that the file is
>   closed when all bytes have been read or an I/O error, or other runtime
>   exception, is thrown.
>
> Note that this method is intended for
>   simple cases where it is convenient to read all bytes into a byte
>   array. It is not intended for reading in large files.

```
public static byte[] readAllBytes(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(path);
         InputStream in = Channels.newInputStream(sbc)) {
        long size = sbc.size();
        if (size > (long)MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)
            throw new OutOfMemoryError("Required array size too large");

        return read(in, (int)size);
    }
}
```